# can't refresh a selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

first excuse my english if it's not correct ...

I've a probleme with a primeface's component, I'm trying to refresh a p:selectOneMenu from a p:commandButton, but it's doesn't work (it 's work on another xhtml page, but not here and I can't understand why ...)

First I select an item from an p:autocomplete which update a backingbean's attribute ( for example : **userChoose** ).

then the p:commandButton is able to call his listener and add **userChoose** to a list, but i can't refresh the selectOneMenu that display the list. I have to use another p:commandButton to refresh the list.

My form is included into a p:tabMenu in another xhtml page.

```
<p:autoComplete id="acPojo" value="#{forumBean.user}" 
             completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.completeUser}" 
             converter="#{userConverter}" forceSelection="true"
             var="usr" itemLabel="#{usr.loginUtilisateur}" itemValue="#{usr}">  

     <p:column>  
        <h:outputText value="#{usr.loginUtilisateur}"/>
     </p:column>                
</p:autoComplete>       

 <p:commandButton value="ajouter" process="acPojo @this " 
    udpate=":tabView:formSujet:listeUser" actionListener="#{forumBean.addUser}"/>

 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{forumBean.user}" converter="#{userConverter}" var="us" id="listeUser" 
                  itemValue="#{us}" itemLabel="#{us.loginUtilisateur}">

       <f:selectItems value="#{forumBean.newSujet.listeUserAllowed}" var="User"
            itemValue="#{User}" itemLabel="#{User.loginUtilisateur}" />

       <p:column>
          <h:outputText value="#{us.loginUtilisateur}"/>
       </p:column>  

       <p:ajax process="@this" />

 </p:selectOneMenu>

 <p:commandButton id="refreshAdmin" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w" 
    update=":tabView:formSujet:listeUser" />
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please post the code of `forumBean.addUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
udpate=":tabView:formSujet:listeUser"
```

This has at least 2 (potential) mistakes. The right attribute name is `update`, not `udpate`. The one on your other button has however the right attribute name.

It that still doesn't work, then the other potential mistake is that the client ID `tabView:formSujet:listeUser` does not exist in HTML DOM tree (and thus JavaScript/jQuery is unable to find and replace it). That can happen if the `<p:tabView>` is dynamic (i.e. you're using `<p:tabView value="#{bean.tabs}" var="tab">`, because it prepents the tab index number in the final client ID like so `tabView:0:formSujet:listeUser` if it's the 1st tab.

But, after all, as both the dropdownlist and the commandbutton are in the same `NamingContainer` parent, you don't need an absolute client ID at all. Just the relative client ID should suffice:

```
update="listeUser"
```

Fix that on your both buttons.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)